# xcodebuild command with absolute path to SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, sdk, xcodebuild

I am using **xcodebuild** command line tool to build iOS app.

After instaling **Xcode45-DP1** it is automatically using 6.0 SDK from the new Xcode45-DP1 app bundle for building applications. There are 2 issues when submitting this app to AppStore.

1. The app is now automatically built with latest SDK (6.0), which is note yet supported, so app cannot be submitted.
   SOLUTION: I copied the old-current SDK (5.1) to Xcode45-DP.app and in command line specified `-sdk iphoneos5.1`
2. Second problem is that when ApplicationLoader is verifying app, is sees that SDK is used from unsupported version of Xcode (45-DP1) and rejects to upload app.
   SOLUTION: I would like to specify absolute path for SDK, like: `xcodebuild -sdk /path/to/5.1sdk...`

The problem is that xcodebuild always says that SDK "/path/to/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/" cannot be located.

Does anyone have an experience with how to use absolute path to sdk and what file/directory should it point to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll need to use the *current* version of Xcode to submit your app, not a developer preview.  Why do you need to use a developer preview anyway?

Comment: Might the 4.5 DP1 be under NDA too? Ask in the Apple developer forums about this.

Comment: That's absolutely true. I don't want to use 4.5 DP1 to build app, but when running xcodebuild from command line, it uses it by default, so I tried copying 5.1SDK into it. I also tried installing old CommandLineTools but it didn't helped.

Comment: @petert I agree, but my question is how to specify absolute path for command line, I don't even want to use the 4.5 DP1 at all.

Comment: Concerning (2), can't you specify the full sdk path in `xcodebuild -sdk ...` - it reads like it does if you see `xcodebuild -help`?

Comment: Also, why don't you have Xcode 4.3.x installed too? Then use `xcode-select` to set Xcode version being used.

Comment: @petert YES, I have specified a fill path to SDK but it shows error that SDK cannot be located at given path. I have installed Xcode lates 4.3 and with xcode-select it solved my problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I have been searching for this for a while as well and there does not appear to be a direct way of getting the full absolute path to a specific SDK.  However, if you set the `-sdk` switch and `-find-library` for an arbitrary library and strip the last few path parts off you can get the full sdk path like so:

```
[ 13:02 jon@MacBookPro ~ ]$ export SYS_ROOT=`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos6.0 -find-library system`
[ 13:02 jon@MacBookPro ~ ]$ echo "${SYS_ROOT/\/usr\/lib\/libsystem.dylib/}"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk

[ 13:02 jon@MacBookPro ~ ]$ export SYS_ROOT=`xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator6.0 -find-library system`
[ 13:02 jon@MacBookPro ~ ]$ echo "${SYS_ROOT/\/usr\/lib\/libsystem.dylib/}"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk
```

Comment: The SYS_ROOT paths can also be obtained this way: "xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path" and "xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path".

Comment: The answer in the comment above by neoneye is much more efficient and reliable. Thanks